Virtual threads seem to block carrier threads on external service call
I have a Spring Boot microservice that consumes messages from a RabbitMQ, composes emails, and sends them to an SMTP server.
It consists of the following components:

Email sender that composes an email end sends it to the SMTP server:

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageSender {

    private final JavaMailSender sender;

    public void sendMessage(final RabbitEmailDto emailDto) {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, emailDto.getTo());

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        helper.setSubject(emailDto.getData().getEmail().getSubject());
        helper.setText(emailDto.getHtml(), true);
        helper.setFrom(emailDto.getFrom());

        sender.send(message);
    }
}


Message processor that gets a list of RabbitMQ messages, for each of them invokes the message sender in a separate virtual thread, and returns a list of futures of the emails send result

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageProcessor {

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
    private final MessageSender messageSender;
    private final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter;

    public List<MessageProcessingFuture> processMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        List<MessageProcessingFuture> processingFutures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Message message : messages) {
            MessageProcessingFuture messageProcessingFuture = new MessageProcessingFuture(
                    message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(),
                    processMessageAsync(message, executor)
            );
            processingFutures.add(messageProcessingFuture);
        }

        return processingFutures;
    }

    private Future<?> processMessageAsync(final Message message) {
        RabbitEmailDto rabbitEmailDto = (RabbitEmailDto) converter.fromMessage(message);
        MessageDeliverySystemEmailDto email = rabbitEmailDto.getData().getEmail();

        return executor.submit(() -> messageSender.sendMessage(rabbitEmailDto));
    }
}


RabbitMQ message listener that consumes messages from the Rabbit queue, passes them to the processor, and then handles the futures it got from the processor by sending acknowledgement or rejection to the RabbitMQ depending on whether the Future.get() threw an exception or did not.

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchMessageListener implements ChannelAwareBatchMessageListener {

    private final MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

    @Override
    @MeasureExecutionTime
    public void onMessageBatch(final List<Message> messages, final Channel channel) {
        messageProcessor.processMessages(messages)
                .forEach(processingFuture -> processFuture(processingFuture, channel));
    }

    private void processFuture(final MessageProcessingFuture future, final Channel channel) {
        try {
            future.deliveryFuture().get();
            channel.basicAck(future.deliveryTag(), false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            channel.basicReject(future.deliveryTag(), false);
        }
    }
}

I can see in logs that the MessageSender.sendMessage method is indeed executing in a virtual thread, identified like VirtualThread[#100]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1.
And I can see that I have 4 of those workers on our production server. (Am I correct that those workers are the actual platform threads, or carrier threads?)
I also see that it usually takes about 1 sec for the MessageSender.sendMessage method to complete, with most of this time spent awaiting a response from the SMTP server.
Based on what I had learned about the virtual threads, I anticipated that processing of a batch of 100 messages (it is my configured batch size for the BatchMessageListener) will take about 1 second because platform threads will not block on the calls to the SMTP server. And those 4 platform threads will be shared among 100 virtual threads, effectively allowing 100 nearly simultaneous calls to the SMTP server.
However, in practice, I have observed that the messages are being processed 4 at a time, and it takes about 25 sec to process all the 100 messages.
During local testing on my computer, I intentionally introduced a 1-second delay by adding the Thread.sleep(1000); before the sender.send(message); line in the MessageSender to simulate network latency. And back then, a batch of 100 messages were indeed processed in just about 1 second, despite the fact that I had only 10 carrier threads according to the logs.
I'm puzzled. Why the carrier threads do not block on the Thead.sleep call, but block on a call of an external service? Do I do something wrong?

Sounds like pinning, when a virtual thread is not dismounted from its carrier thread. See the article, Java Virtual Thread Pinning, by Todd Ginsberg for a guide on how to detect pinning. He describes how to detect pinning by (1) logging, and by (2) use of Java Flight Recorder (JFR). Pinning is usually due to (a) use of synchronized around long-running code, or (b) calling native code via JNI etc.

You are eventually calling Thread.sleep() 100 times simultaniously on the same thread. Making it effectively sleep way shorter than 100s. That is just a guess.

Your network latency is 1 second? You should really be focusing on fixing your network then.

@BasilBourque tanks a lot.
I see that the org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender, which I use, is calling several synchronized methods while sending an email. Am I getting it correct that there isn't much that can be done to benefit from the virtual treads in this case?

@AlexKolokolov can you elaborate on what synchronized methods are invoked within org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender? and update the question with the pinned threads stack trace(-Djdk.tracePinnedThreads) corresponding to it.

@Naman the JavaMailSender.send method calls synchronized methods protocolConnect, getAuthorizationId, and sendMessage of the org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport class under the hood.
Apologies, I can't share the actual stack traces as I'm working on proprietary software covered by an NDA.

Yes, I could see a few methods of the implementation to be synchronized by the Javadoc, just wanted to confirm the ones in the trace that you could observe.

You wrote "Why the carrier threads do not block on the Thead.sleep call, but block on a call of an external service?" Did you mean pin on the Thread.sleep?  If any thread, virtual or platform, is not blocked by Thread.sleep, by other words, is allowed to go ahead without suspending for a certain amount of time, then this is a gigantic bug in a JVM implementation.  Pinning and blocking are very different phenomena.

To detect pinning, you should be running JFR on your executing code, rather than putting eyeballs on source code. Programmers of all skill levels are notoriously poor at predicting performance problems at runtime.

@igor.zh Thread.sleep did block virtual threads. All the 100 virtual threads in my case where blocked for 1 sec and released simultaneously. And that behaviour I was expecting from the virtual threads.
I did not notice any pinning on the following sender.send call because locally it lasted for only few milliseconds. I did not use the term pinning in my question because I knew nothing about the pinning at the time I was posting it.

@BasilBourque I did detect pinning using the tracePinnedThreads.
I took a look into the lib source code just to make sure that indeed most of JavaMailSender.send method logic executes inside a synchronised method.

OK, nice to hear that Thread.sleep still works as expected :) If it is indeed pinning could you edit your question and mention pinning instead of  blocking so that more to-the-point answer could be given? Thanks for answering!

@igor.zh pinning is a key answer to my question, it cannot be in the question itself. If I had known of pinning before there would have been no question.
So, I will not edit the question to let the others, who are not yet aware of pinning, come across the question and learn about pinning from the answer.

@igor.zh actually, the question’s wording is correct. It uses the term “blocking” in reference to the carrier thread, which happens because the virtual thread is pinned. From the carrier thread’s perspective, nothing special happens here. It’s blocked, the same way other platform threads can get blocked.

@Holger, yes, if pinning may happen only when the carrier thread is blocking, as Oracle suggests. Note, however, that initially I confronted "the carrier threads do not block on the Thread.sleep call" statement, which is nearly impossible, but would make perfect sense if blocking is replaced with pinning.

@igor.zh it’s the other way round, a carrier thread may get blocked when the virtual thread is pinned (and performs a blocking action while pinned). Being pinned only means that a virtual thread can not unmount from it’s carrier thread. This term is not a replacement for blocking. So, the original statement is valid if you keep in mind that it is the virtual thread executing the sleep call: “the carrier thread does (usually) not block on the virtual thread’s sleep call” but note that the virtual thread might be pinned already, e.g. when calling sleep inside a synchronized block

@Holger, How can this happen that the carrier thread does (usually) not block (!) on the virtual thread’s sleep call”. Thread.sleep has to block any thread, isn't it its sole purpose? Its javadoc says: "Causes the ... thread to ... temporarily cease execution". Do I misread the javadoc or do we have different understanding of thread blocking? Blocking to me is LockSupport.park, entering  a section synchronized  on a contended monitor, join and of course sleep. Spin waiting and CAS, e.g. in AQS, are non-blocking. What do I miss here?

@igor.zh when the virtual thread performs a sleep call, the virtual thread gets blocked. The carrier thread is not blocked but will proceed to execute a different virtual thread. That’s the whole point of virtual threads. That’s what usually happens. But when the virtual thread is pinned when performing the sleep call, the carrier thread will get blocked too. That’s what pinned means, the inability to unmount, so the carrier thread can not do something else.

@Holger, yes, that makes perfect sense. Carrier, when it stumbles on blocking operation, just gets dispatched to another virtual thread or returned to the ForkJoinPool - ideally. In this sense both virtual and platform get blocked on sleep, but carrier (which is, again, platform  :) ) does not. A  question: when you said "the carrier thread does (usually) not block on the virtual thread", by usually  did you mean that when it does block, it is a cause (or a good reason) for pinning of the virtual thread, mounted on this carrier?

@igor.zh reasons for the carrier thread to get blocked when the virtual thread executes a sleep call might be that the virtual thread is pinned or that you you are running on a custom jre implementation where virtual thread support for sleep has not been implemented (yet).

Pinning
Sounds like pinning, when a virtual thread is not dismounted from its carrier thread.
Pinning is usually due to:

Use of synchronized around long-running code.
Calling native code via Java Native Interface (JNI) etc.

If you have four carrier threads (platform threads dedicated to serving virtual threads), and these virtual threads are pinned much of the time, then you have effectively limited the work throughput to those four carrier threads. The remaining 96 of 100 tasks must wait until the first four complete, then 92 wait until the next four complete, and so on. In such a case, you should be using platform threads rather than virtual threads. The virtual threads are of no benefit, and are actually creating extra work.
Detect pinning
See the article, Java Virtual Thread Pinning, by Todd Ginsberg for a guide on how to detect pinning. He describes how to detect pinning by:

Logging.
Use of JDK Flight Recorder (JFR).

You can view JFR results with JDK Mission Control (JMC).
Note that you can adjust the threshold for detecting pinning. I vaguely recall the default is 20 milliseconds. But you should verify and decide your own useful value.
Workarounds/alternatives
You later Commented:

I see that the org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender, which I use, is calling several synchronized methods while sending an email. Am I getting it correct that there isn't much that can be done to benefit from the virtual treads in this case?

Correct… if that synchronized code is long-running.
Virtual threads are not appropriate for tasks that involve long-running code  that is either synchronized or native (JNI, etc.). In both cases the JVM’s virtual thread scheduler is unable to see when such code is blocked, so it remains assigned to the platform carrier thread.
For occasional encounters, this situation is no big deal. But for repeated or sustained encounters, this situation means you will get little or no benefit from virtual threads, and virtual threads may actually impair overall performance. Sounds like your case fits the “repeated or sustained encounters“ category.
The Project Loom team continues to look for ways around the synchronized limitation. But still an issue as of Java 21 & 22.
Replacing synchronized with ReentrantLock
If the synchronized code is your own, then replace any long-running uses of synchronized with a ReentrantLock to regain efficiency with virtual threads. That change is simple enough.
Some folks have misinterpreted this guidance as “replace all use of synchronized with ReentrantLock”. This is not necessary. Only long-running synchronized code need be modified. Brief code, such as guarding access to a variable that is usually available, can be left in place as so little time is spent within the synchronized code.
If you cannot modify the source code of long-running synchronized tasks, then use platform threads rather than virtual threads. But keep in mind, if  those tasks have multiple sub-tasks that can be multi-threaded, the task in a platform thread may benefit from running those sub-tasks with virtual threads.
For more info
I'm no expert on this. So listen to the experts, not me.

Study the basic requirements document outlining the feature, JEP 444: Virtual Threads
See video presentations by Project Loom team members Alan Bateman and Ron Pressler.
See explanatory talks by José Paumard.
Occasionally look at the Project Loom project page.

